# Создание таблицы в Python

Tags: python, table, рефакторинг

Вот так я написал таблицу:

```
data = [["Категории", "Цена"],
        {"book": 58, "organization": 0, "homegum": 55, "summer": 1,
        "win": 85189}]


def create_table(data, header_separator=True):

    header_cols = len(data[0])

    # Сделал чтобы строки "Категории" и "Цена", вывводились
    # в качестве заголовка
    elem_col1 = [data[0][0]] + list(data[1].keys())
    elem_col2 = [data[0][1]] + list(map(str, list(data[1].values())))

    # Определяет ширину для каждого столбика

    col_width = [len(max(elem_col1, key=len)),
                 len(max(elem_col2, key=len))]

    # Границы заголовков столбцов
    separator = "-+-".join('-' * n for n in col_width)

    # Создание таблицы
    i = 0
    for col in range(len(elem_col1)):
        if i == 1:
            print(separator)
        result = [elem_col1[col].rjust(col_width[0]),
                  elem_col2[col].rjust(col_width[1])]
        i += 1
        print(" | ".join(result))


create_table(data)
```

Как написать её лучше и правильней? (с такими же входными данными)

Comment: Особо никак. Если работает (а оно, вроде, работает), то зачем вам ещё что-то?

Comment: Я бы вместо словаря как тела таблицы использовал список списков

Comment: а я бы использовал pandas

Comment: Reymi, отметьте и примите, пожалуйста, ответ, что решает вашу проблему :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется, данными таблицы должны быть списки/кортежи, а в случаи словаря его нужно приводить к необходимому виду

Плюс, количество столбцов, из-за использования тела как словаря, будет 2, думаю нужно поддержать произвольное количество столбцов

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/21ab50c6f081e71d8e6342a12cefe035f54396ff/ascii_table__simple_pretty__rjust.py#L7)

```
def pretty_table(data, cell_sep=' | ', header_separator=True) -> str:
    rows = len(data)
    cols = len(data[0])

    col_width = []
    for col in range(cols):
        columns = [str(data[row][col]) for row in range(rows)]
        col_width.append(len(max(columns, key=len)))

    separator = "-+-".join('-' * n for n in col_width)

    lines = []

    for i, row in enumerate(range(rows)):
        result = []
        for col in range(cols):
            item = str(data[row][col]).rjust(col_width[col])
            result.append(item)

        lines.append(cell_sep.join(result))

        if i == 0 and header_separator:
            lines.append(separator)

    return '\n'.join(lines)
```

Использование:

```
data = [
    ["Категории", "Цена"],
    {"book": 58, "organization": 0, "homegum": 55, "summer": 1, "win": 85189}
]
rows = [
    data[0]
]
rows += [(k, v) for k, v in data[1].items()]
print(pretty_table(rows))
```

Результат:

```
   Категории |  Цена
-------------+------
        book |    58
organization |     0
     homegum |    55
      summer |     1
         win | 85189
```

Answer (score 0):

можно еще попробовать Format specifications, получится что-то вроде этого:

```
data = [
    ["Категории", "Цена"],
    {"book": 58, "organization": 0, "homegum": 55, "summer": 1, "win": 85189}
]

print('{0:^14}|{1:^8}'.format(*data[0]), '-' * 14 + '+' + '-' * 8,
      '\n'.join('{0:<14}|{1:>8}'.format(*i) for i in data[1].items()),sep='\n')
```

результат:

```
  Категории   |  Цена  
--------------+--------
book          |      58
organization  |       0
homegum       |      55
summer        |       1
win           |   85189
```